# Fail2ban ignoreip command crashing fail2ban

Tags: 16.04, fail2ban

Recently I updated ubuntu 16.04 with the latest security updates and all of a sudden ignoreip stops fail2ban from running
I comment this line out and it starts working
Any ideas? i tried adding commas and ignoreip for each in my jail.local file

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the comman from jail.local to fail2ban.conf and it started working again? I ran for almost a year in jail.local